# Using hashes and arrays in Perl

Tags: arrays, perl

Below I am trying to read data from a file and trying to store them in an array. The array size in this case should be 6 as highest value of round is 6 (1,2,3,4,5,6).

I am expecting an array of 6 elements having some number. Please help me where I am going wrong. I am new to perl.

```
if ( !defined($ARGV[0]) ) { print "ENTER OUTPUT Filename\n"; exit 1; }
$outputFile = $ARGV[0];
open(HND, "$outputFile");
while (<HND>)
{
    chomp;
    my $line = $_;
    if ( /Node (.*) sending (.*) data to BS at time (.*)  node 0 round (.*)$/ )
    {
        my $round = $4;
        my $data  = $2;
        if ( exists($CHenergy{$round}) )
        {
            $CHenergy{$round} += $data;
        }
        else
        {
            $CHenergy{$round} = $data;
        }
    }
}
close HND;
print join(", ", $CHenergy);
```

At then end I am printing values of the array but it is printing nothing.

Comment: ALWAYS `use strict; use warnings;` at the begining of your scripts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You *must always* add `use strict` and `use warnings` to the top of every Perl program, and declare all your variables using `my`. In this instance it would have told you that there was no hash `%CHenergy`.

Remember that Perl has three primary data types -- scalars, that start with `$`; arrays, that start with `@`; and hashes, that start with `%`. And they may share identifiers, for instance, `$data`, `@data`, and `%data` can all exist at the same time and are independent from one another. Hash values are indexed using square brackers `[...]` and array values are indexed using braces `{...}`, but because a single value is a *scalar*, they both start with `$`; for instance `$data[0]` and `$data{key}`.

You are using *braces* `{ .. }` to index what you thought was an array, but `$CHenergy{$round}` is indexing the *hash* `%CHenergy`. `@ARGV` is an array, and you have indexed that successfully with brackets `[ .. ]`. You need to access array `@CHenergy` in the same way.

You should also use lower-case letters, digits and underscore to name local variables. Capital letters are reserved for global identifiers.

I have modified your program, to show a better way of writing it, and have used `printf` to format the data.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($input_file) = @ARGV;

unless ( $input_file ) {
  warn "Enter input filename\n";
  exit 1;
}

open my ($hnd), '<', $input_file or die $!;

my @ch_energy;
while (<$hnd>) {
   next unless /Node (.*) sending (.*) data to BS at time (.*)  node 0 round (.*)/;
   my ($data, $round) = ($2, $4);
   $ch_energy[$round] += $data;
}

for my $i (0 .. $#ch_energy) {
   my $energy = $ch_energy[$i];
   printf "%2d => %d\n", $i, $energy if defined $energy;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It isn't an array, you are using a hash (`%CHenergy`). To print its keys:

```
my @the_keys = keys %CHenergy;
print join(", ", @the_keys), "\n";
```

The module [Data::Dumper](https://metacpan.org/pod/Data::Dumper) may helps you to show the variable contents:

```
use Data::Dumper;
#...
print Dumper(%CHenergy), "\n";
```

**Note**: use the modern perl approach to handle files:

```
open (HND,"$outputFile");
```

should be (replace HND by $HND in the rest of your code):

```
open my $HND, ">", "$outputFile" or die $!;
```

Comment: It is giving me output like this
$VAR1 = '6';
$VAR2 = 78956;
$VAR3 = '4';
$VAR4 = 40271;
$VAR5 = '1';
$VAR6 = 26731;
$VAR7 = '3';
$VAR8 = 39792;
$VAR9 = '2';
$VAR10 = 30111;
$VAR11 = '5';
$VAR12 = 62232;

How can I format it to.

1 some number
2 some number
..

Comment: @MuhammadZaighum: use this: `print Dumper\%CHenergy;`, notice the backslash.

Answer (score 0):

You should `use strict` and `use warnings`. Beside it's primary function, it will help you to understand some of the Perl's principles and features.

As pointed out, the `CHenergy` variable is not an array, but a hash. If you want to use an array (which is perhaps a little more suitable for this problem), you must prefix the variable with the at-sign (`my @array`)  and access the members of the array using square brackets instead of braces (`$array[0]`).

This is how I would have done it:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my $filename = shift or die "You must supply an input file.";
open my $fh, $filename or die $!;

my @CHenergy = (0,0,0,0,0,0);

while (<$fh>) {

    if ( /Node (.*) sending (.*) data to BS at time (.*)  node 0 round (.*)$/ ) {
        my $data  = $2;
        my $round = $4; # replace with "$4 - 1" when 
                        # the round is from 1 to 6
                        # instead of 0 to 5

        $CHenergy[$round] += $data;
    }
}

close $fh;
print join(", ", @CHenergy);
```

As a following edit to the program, I suggest to alter the regular expression (particularly the double space after the third pair of parentheses). If you are not using the fields `$1` and `$3`, then don't include them in the regex. You can also perform a validation on the fields to ensure there is a number on the line:

```
/^Node .* sending ([0-9]+) data to BS at time .* node 0 round ([0-5])$/
```

Also note that the `chomp` statement is not necessarry - the newline is matched by the dollar sign in the regular expression.